# Windows Server 2003 will not load explorer.exe

Tags: windows-server-2003

The server is a virtual machine running in Hyper-V. The OS is Windows Server 2003, SP2 and I am unable to open Windows Explorer in the VM. When, I launch it, it never opens. Eventually, I ge an Event ID 1004 in the Application log which tells me that explorer.exe faulted and the faulting module is shell32.exe. Any one have any pointers on how to repair explorer?

Thanks!